# Ignoring an invalid field when deserializing json in Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize some json from a 3rd party provider, and occasionally it returns some invalid date field (like -0001-01-01 or something). This causes the process to throw an exception.

Is there a way to tell Json.Net to ignore fields that are invalid?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: You should probably look at the underlying cause of the invalid data, and repair it if possible first, before trying to work around it.

Comment: It looks like this field is set to `DateTime.MinValue`.  That's not necessarily "invalid".  Since `DateTime` is a value type it can't be null; if you want to allow that, think about making your value type fields `Nullable`.

Comment: You can mark a property with [XmlIgnore] attribute if you don't want it serialized

Comment: @auburg, You probably meant `[JsonIgnore]`

Comment: maybe this can help you. This explain how to manage deserialization errors in json.net
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107656/ignore-parsing-errors-during-json-net-data-parsing

Comment: The problem is not with JSON serialization. Even if JSON.Net would ignore it, you'll end up with `default(DateTime)` because `DateTime` is a value-type. Consider using a nullable `DateTime?`.

Comment: What part of 'the process' throws an exception?  As others have said, you could look into extending your converter.  This covers extending Newtonsft:  http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/using-a-custom-jsonconverter-to-fix-bad-json-results/

Comment: Lots to answer: I have no control over the source data. The field actually has a minus sign in front of it but I do need to check that properly. I don't want to ignore it except when its invalid. The field I'm mapping to is actually a Nullable DateTime. And finally the DeserializeObject method throws the exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on the answer from David, I have used a custom DateTime converter:

```
public class SafeDateTimeConvertor : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        DateTime result;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), out result))
            return result;
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

Which is then applied like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(json, new SafeDateTimeConvertor());
```

Comment: Instead of specifying format explicitly, you can use ((DateTime)value).toString("o") - it corresponds to ISO 8601 format

Comment: You can also decorate desired attribute with [JsonConverter(typeof(SafeDateTimeConvertor))] (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256323/json-net-serialize-datetime-minvalue-as-null)

Answer (score 1):

JSON.NET has numerous ways to control serialization.  You might look at [Conditional Property (De)Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) for example.

There's an entire topic in the online docs on [Serializing Dates](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm).

You could write a custom converter; see the documentation for the [Newtonsoft.Json.Converters](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters.htm) namespace.

Comment: I think the custom converter is the way to go, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It happens, third parties can neglect type safety in their JSON. I recommend you contact them. I had a scenario where a property was either a string array or "false". Json.NET didn't like this so as a temporary hack, I created this custom converter to ignore the deserialization exception:

```
public class IgnoreDataTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try { return JToken.Load(reader).ToObject(objectType); }
        catch { }
        return objectType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) : null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

This "TryConvert" approach is not advised. Use it as a temporary solution after you send your thoughts to the designers of the originating JSON you are consuming.