# Force JSON.NET to include milliseconds AND output null for a null date field when serializing DateTime

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having trouble with `DateTimeFormat` in  Newtonsoft.Json.  The API that I am publishing to requires milliseconds on all of the dates.  The object I am serializing has a number of date fields, and some of these are null for some of the data.

I can't seem to get the JSON to output both null for the null dates AND inlucde the milliseconds in the fields that have dates.  I can get one or other working, but not both together.

Pretty sure it is something small, but I've not managed to get to the bottom of it and I've spent a few days at it.

This correctly outputs null, but does not include milliseconds:

```
public string ToJson()
{   
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new MinDateTimeConverter()).ToString();
}
    
public class MinDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public MinDateTimeConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'";
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null)
            return DateTime.MinValue;

        return (DateTime)reader.Value;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        DateTime dateTimeValue = (DateTime)value;
        if (dateTimeValue == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
"dateOfBirth": "1943-03-02T00:00:00Z",  

"dateOfDeath": null`
```

This correctly outputs dates including milliseconds, but null dates are converted to a `DateTime` as well:

```
public string ToJson()
{           
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'" }).ToString();
}
```

This is the output:

```
"dateOfBirth": "1943-03-02T00:00:00.000Z",

"dateOfDeath": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

I've looked at both the below SO articles but can't get them to work together.

[Force JSON.NET to include milliseconds when serializing DateTime (even if ms component is zero)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193281/force-json-net-to-include-milliseconds-when-serializing-datetime-even-if-ms-com)

[JSON.NET Serialize DateTime.MinValue as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256323/json-net-serialize-datetime-minvalue-as-null)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `ReadJson` and `WriteJson` methods in your `MinDateTimeConverter` do not call the base class, so the normal processing that handles the custom date format in the non-null case never happens.  Here is the corrected code:

```
public class MinDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public MinDateTimeConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'";
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(DateTime) && reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return DateTime.MinValue;

        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTime date && date == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }
        
        base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x8PAzf

Comment: Perfect, works great.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help!