# How to ignore data row if there's an error during json Deserialisation

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need a way to ignore rows / items that fail JsonProperty (throws an error) within a large list that's provided to newtonsoft JsonCovert as JSON.

Currently utilising [this question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107656/ignore-parsing-errors-during-json-net-data-parsing) as a based to handle the errors which was working well until a couple cases.

Using this flow where the error context is not handled:

```
var currentError = errorArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = false;
```

It doesn't return any items, even those that do pass validation in the string

Using this flow however:

```
var currentError = errorArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
```

All the items are serialized, the error is thrown on those properties that have
`JsonProperty("property_name", Required = Required.Always, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)` or `JsonRequired`

and they're still included in the list, which causes errors down the line when this list is being bulk fed into a database.

Ultimately, I would like to know if there is a way to not include items in the resulting list that have failed, rather than taking all of them or none at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix that I was able to figure out was to:

Get the errorArgs.ErrorContent.path in the format "[*index*]" and strip out the '[' and ']', parse this to an integer, store it in a list.

Set error handled to true for all cases, and then once the deserialization had completed I then used this list of integers to remove the offending items