# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject with different property types needs to continue even after failing but collect the list of errors

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I need to deserialize a class with different types (int, float, string, guid) of properties. I am hoping to find a way to do this so that:

- if a value does not match it's expected type an error would be added to an error list
- and continue with the deserialization to have the full list of errors rather than just the first one

Example

```
public record Row()    

[JsonProperty("columnName")]
public string? ColumnName { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("entityCode")]
public Guid? EntityCode { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("numberValue")]
public float? NumberValue { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("integerValue")]
public int? IntegerValue { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("booleanValue")]
public bool? BooleanValue { get; set; }
```

Object example

```
"Row": [
{
    "columnName": "category",
    "entityCode": "not a guid"
},
{
    "columnName": "numberValue",
    "numberValue": "not a number"
},
{
    "columnName": "value",
    "stringValue": 104.28398
},
{
    "columnName": "value",
    "booleanValue": "not a bool"
}
```

],

And then I need to defserialize the object above
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Row>>`

But instead of instantly jumping to an exception with one error I need to know all the properties that have wrong types.

Can this be done?

Comment: Give examples of what the input looks like and what should happen.

Comment: Use a JSON Schema Validation step: https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema

Comment: To continue after an error use the event [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationerrorhandling.htm) and set `args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;` as shown in [Ignore parsing errors during JSON.NET data parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26107656).  Does that question fully answer yours?

Comment: That being said, it is unwise to continue from a [`JsonReaderException`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonreaderexception.htm) as that exception indicates a malformed JSON file (rather than a file whose contents cannot be deserialized to the required type.).  Trying to continue from such an error can result in an infinite loop e.g. when the file is truncated.

Comment: I smell [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Are you trying to validate JSON by trying to deserialize it and get all the errors? If so, there are more appropriate approaches to that, for example [JsonSchema](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step#validate).

Comment: I guess the answer is that I should not try to deserialize and validate at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did not provided correct class structure.
you can do with custom serializing settings

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"Row\":[{\"columnName\":\"category\",\"entityCode\":\"not a guid\"},{\"columnName\":\"numberValue\",\"numberValue\":\"not a number\"},{\"columnName\":\"value\",\"stringValue\":104.28398},{\"columnName\":\"value\",\"booleanValue\":\"not a bool\"}]}";
    
    var errors = new List<string>();
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        Error = (s, e) =>
        {
            var _Obj = e.CurrentObject as Row;
            if (_Obj != null)
            {
                errors.Add($"Error on {_Obj.ColumnName}: {e.ErrorContext.Error.Message}");
            }
            else
            {
                errors.Add(e.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
            }
            e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    };
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, settings).Dump();
    if(errors.Count>0)
        errors.Dump();
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Row> Row { get; set; }
}
public record Row()
{

    [JsonProperty("columnName")]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("entityCode")]
    public Guid? EntityCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numberValue")]
    public float? NumberValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("integerValue")]
    public int? IntegerValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("booleanValue")]
    public bool? BooleanValue { get; set; }
}
```

results:
[image]

**UPDATE**:
this is definetly XY problem

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"Row\":[{\"columnName\":\"category\",\"entityCode\":\"not a guid\"},{\"columnName\":\"numberValue\",\"numberValue\":\"not a number\"},{\"columnName\":123,\"stringValue\":104.28398},{\"columnName\":\"value\",\"booleanValue\":\"not a bool\"}]}";

    var errors = new List<string>();
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        Error = (s, e) =>
        {
            var _Obj = e.CurrentObject as Row;
            if (_Obj != null)
            {
                errors.Add($"Error on {_Obj.ColumnName}: {e.ErrorContext.Error.Message}");
            }
            else
            {
                errors.Add(e.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
            }
            e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    };
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, settings).Dump();
    if (errors.Count > 0)
        errors.Dump();
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Row> Row { get; set; }
}
public record Row()
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StrictStringConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("columnName")]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("entityCode")]
    public Guid? EntityCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numberValue")]
    public float? NumberValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("integerValue")]
    public int? IntegerValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("booleanValue")]
    public bool? BooleanValue { get; set; }
}

public class StrictStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    readonly JsonSerializer defaultSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsIntegerType();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.String:
                    return defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
            case JsonToken.Integer:
            case JsonToken.Float: // Accepts numbers like 4.00
                throw new JsonSerializationException($"Value \"{reader.Value}\" of type {reader.TokenType} was not a string");
            case JsonToken.Null:
                return defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
            default:
                return defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
                
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static bool IsIntegerType(this Type type)
    {
        type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;
        if (type == typeof(long)
            || type == typeof(ulong)
            || type == typeof(int)
            || type == typeof(uint)
            || type == typeof(short)
            || type == typeof(ushort)
            || type == typeof(byte)
            || type == typeof(sbyte)
            || type == typeof(System.Numerics.BigInteger))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DHjq5L

Comment: But more importantly, it is not failing on a string even though the value is not a string.

Comment: updated. included Json custom converter

Comment: Thanks! 
With some AI help I have written the ReadJson somewhat differently though

public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
    Type objectType,
    object? existingValue,
    JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String)
    {
        Errors.Add($"Error on {reader.Path.Split('.').Last()}: Expected string value, but got {reader.TokenType}.");
        return null!;
    }

    return reader.Value!;
}